# Moments of derivatives of $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, moments

I'd like to know why it is important to know the moments of the derivatives of $L$-functions.
The moments of $L$-functions are related to the Lindelöf Hypothesis, but what about the moments of the derivatives?
I'd like to know if someone has a reference about this subject.

Comment: If you're studying a family of $L$-functions where the sign of the functional equation is zero, then the central $L$-values are clearly zero, and the derivative may encode non-trivial information (e.g. think of BSD conjectures).   In this family it would be of interest to study the distribution of the values of the derivatives.  More generally, it would be fair to say that the study of values of (for example) the derivative of the Riemann zeta-function is less central than the values of zeta itself.  Although, knowledge about derivatives can give information about zeros (Levinson's idea).

Comment: @Lucia : I expected what you call the sign of the functional equation to be the root number  $ \omega $ such that the considered functional equation takes the form  $ \Lambda(k-s)=\omega\Lambda(s) $ if  $ \omega $  is real, so that it should be  $ -1 $ to entail the vanishing of the central value. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Another example of the derivatives of $L$-functions encoding arithmetic information is the Gross-Zagier formula (and its extensions by Zhang), which interpret $L'(1/2, \pi \otimes \pi_{\chi})$ as the "height" of some Heegner cycle above some Shimura curve.

Comment: @SylvianJULIEN, that is exactly what Lucia means by the sign of the functional equation (there is a typo where "zero" is written instead of "minus one").

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: The correct functional equation is $\Lambda(s)=\omega\overline{\Lambda(1-\overline{s})}$, where I put the center at $s=1/2$ as usual. That is, a complete $L$-function at $s$ equals $\omega$ times the dual $L$-function at $1-s$. This implies $|\omega|=1$. If the $L$-function is self-dual (i.e. equals its dual), then $\omega$ is either $+1$ or $-1$. For example, for a Dirichlet-character $\chi$, $L(s,\chi)$ is self-dual if and only if $\chi$ is a quadratic Dirichlet character.

Comment: Indeed. I got mistaken with the functional equation of the Riemann Zeta function which is obviously self-dual. Thanks to all and especially GH from MO for reminding me the basics.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Let's also not forget that the factor $N^{s/2}$, where $N\in\mathbb{N}$ is the conductor of the $L$-function, is usually not included in $\Lambda(s)$. That is, the two sides of the formula should be multiplied by $N^{s/2}$ and $N^{(1-s)/2}$, respectively: $N^{s/2}\Lambda(s)=\omega N^{(1-s)/2}\overline{\Lambda(1-\overline{s})}$.